# How to change the command prompt for a C# console application

Tags: c#, console, command-prompt

I am building a `C#` console application and want to customize the prelude symbol to something else such as **"> "**. I checked the properties of class `Console` and could not find any one doing this job. As a workaround, in the code I write a "> " symbol before writing any new line. But this is not a perfect solution, especially when there is a background worker thread printing messages, sometimes the prelude symbol will be lost because the work thread may write message earlier before the main thread writing a prelude.

I searched web but did not find any hint, is there a standard solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a standard solution for this?

No.

Aphelion hits the nail on the head when he says to create a custom class to handle this.

```
   public static class I
 {
    public string preclude = ">";
    public static void WriteLine(string message)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(preclude+message);
    }
    public static void ReadLine()
    {
     Console.Write(preclude);Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

Because you have a background thread writing to the console you should also have a check to make sure you don't have conflicting write lines such as when you ask for user input. You will have to implement `Console.MoveBufferArea` in your thread which writes while the user is asked for input otherwise you will have an issue if the user is in the middle of typing.

It will be easy to update in your code too just replace Console.WriteLine with I.Console.WriteLine.

Comment: When the solution already uses IoC I would recommend to 'inject' it using an `IConsoleWriter` interface to enable testing and not calling static classes from within code.

Comment: [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) has a bunch of overloads. Personally I wouldn't provide all the ones for the several base datatypes, but at least one with `object[]` seems usefull for string formatting.

Comment: @CodeCamper, let's think this scenario: the application calls "I.ReadLine" and was waiting user input, so this time there is a "> " on the screen. But now, before user inputting, a background thread wants to print some message, so it calls "I.WriteLine", so we could imagine the result is there are 2 prelude symbols "> > " leading the line.

Comment: When your background thread writes to the screen you should implement `Console.MoveBufferArea` which will also solve the additional problem of interrupting the user while he is typing. I personally would not use `ReadLine` at all and I always use a series of `ReadKey`s this way I can have more control over the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not possible out of the box, I would suggest to provide an custom class that encapsulates the `Console` class that you will use from within the background threads to write messages to the console. This will also make unit testing easier.

```
public class ClassInOtherThread
{
    private readonly IConsoleWriter _consoleWriter;

    public ClassInOtherThread(IConsoleWriter consoleWriter)
    {
        this._consoleWriter = consoleWriter;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _consoleWriter.Write("something");
    }
}

public interface IConsoleWriter
{
    void Write(string value);
}

public class ConsoleWriter : IConsoleWriter
{
    public void Write(string value)
    {
        // Fix your >  problems in this class
        Console.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to see how you `'inject' it using an IConsoleWriter interface to enable testing` as I have never done this before.